# jQuery DatePicker is not working in php using mongodb database?

Tags: php, jquery, mongodb

I am trying to filter my MongoDB data by using jQuery calendar but it is giving an **error** `Undefined variable: start` and `Undefined variable: end` , I am unable to figure out how can I define my query value and put into MongoDB query to filter according to the date selected.

Code - **MongoDB query**

```
    $collection= $client->db_name->collection;
//default date selected
$currentdate = date("Y-m-d");

$filter = [array('date' => array('$gt' => start, '$lte' => end)),'date' => $currentdate]; 
$options = [];
$cursor= $collection->find($filter, $options)->toArray();
```

Here is my **jQuery Calendar code**

```
 $(function () {
        var start = moment();
        var end = moment();
        function cb(start, end) {
            $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' - ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            $('#hidreportrange').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

            $("#spncurrentDate").html(DataBaseManager.DateTimeFormat(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')));
        }
        $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
            "singleDatePicker": true,
            startDate: start,
            endDate: end,
            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')]
            }, 

            locale: {
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            }
        }, cb);

        cb(start, end);
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try defining your start and end variables on your datepicker like this:

```
daterangepicker.daterangepicker("setRange", {
        start: moment("{{ startDate }}").toDate(),
        end: moment("{{ endDate }}").toDate()
    });
```

In my case i'm using  'startDate' and 'endDate' as variables sent from the controller but you can use whatever you need.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that my daterangepicker refences my html id:

```
let daterangepicker = $("#daterangepicker");
```